# How to scroll over aframe scene on mobile devices

Tags: html, aframe

Is there a way to scroll over aframe on mobile devices, I tried to disable the controls of the scene but still can't scroll, and it keeps interacting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach - create an overlay element over the scene, which will prevent interaction and

- hide the overlay when it's "double tapped"
- show the overlay when anything outside the scene is clicked

So lets say somewhere within you scrollable content you have a **HTML** setup like this:

```
<div id="aframe-content">
  <div id="aframe-overlay"></div>
  <a-scene embedded>
      <!-- cool stuff --->
  </a-scene>
</div>
```

and the **css** set up so that the overlay works within a scrollable column:

```
#aframe-content {
  position: relative;
}

#aframe-overlay {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: absolute;
}

a-scene, #aframe-overlay {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

we only need to add the **js** responsible for hiding / showing the overlay:

```
const overlay = document.querySelector("#aframe-overlay");
const acanvas = document.querySelector("canvas.a-canvas")
// helper boolean, so that on each touch we don't need to compare HTML elements
var overlayHidden = false; 

function setOverlay(enabled) {
  overlayHidden = !enabled
  overlay.style.display = overlayHidden ? "none" : "block";
}

function hideOverlay(evt) {
  if (overlayHidden && evt.target !== acanvas) {
    setOverlay(true)
  }
}

var showOverlay = setOverlay.bind(this, false)
overlay.addEventListener("dblclick", showOverlay);
window.addEventListener("click", hideOverlay);
window.addEventListener("touchstart", hideOverlay);
```

You can check it out [in this glitch](https://aframe-mobile-scroll.glitch.me/) which seems to be working both on PC and mobile. Click on the fish to see the source code.

Comment: Thank you, I am using a full screen scene that appears after scrolling to a certain point, for that I kept the overlay displayed, only if a dialog appears (for iOS devices asking for permission) it is hidden and then reappears after clicking on a button